# How do we enable code reviews in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc, azure-devops-server-2020

Our company has multiple projects, and uses code reviews in most of them. However in one decades-old project we get the following message: "This feature can't be used until your Azure DevOps administrator has enabled it on the team project."

[image]

In Visual Studio / Team Explorer / Pending Actions, I drop down the list of Actions, and select 'Request Review' to get the above message.

We can't find the setting to enable code reviews, and google can't find any mentions of the error message.

We're still using Team Foundation version control, not Git.
We are on "Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1"

The closest match I've found on the web is [this](https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2018/03/22/update-a-tfs-team-project-manually-to-support-code-reviews/) but it's not quite the same, and I'm reluctant to poke around with the templates without understanding them. It is quite possible that this project has been imported from our old Source Safe system some time ago though, the history is murky.

Comment: Which version of Azure DevOps are you using?

Comment: @jessehouwing Version: Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a new feature enablement wizard in versions up to Team Foundation Server 2018, It has now been removed. So now you'll have to do this manually. [The blog post you referenced looks correct at first glance.](https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2018/03/22/update-a-tfs-team-project-manually-to-support-code-reviews/).

What you need to do is to make sure the right work item types, categories and relationships exist in your team project.

[This official doc lists the steps to take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/reference/upgrade/add-features-manually?view=tfs-2017&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#update-a-project). You'll need to:

- [Download the latest process template: Get the definitions you need to import or update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/reference/upgrade/add-features-manually?view=tfs-2017&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#download-latest-pt)
- [Import WITs: Code Review Request and Code Review Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/reference/upgrade/add-features-manually?view=tfs-2017&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#import-wit)
- [Update Categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/reference/upgrade/add-features-manually?view=tfs-2017&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#update-categories):

  - Add the Code Review Request and Code Review Response Categories
  - Add the Code Review Request and Code Review Response Categories to the Hidden Types Category
- [Update ProcessConfiguration: Add work item colors for Code Review Request and Code Review Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/reference/upgrade/add-features-manually?view=tfs-2017&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#update-processconfig)
- [To verify, create a code review request.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh474795.aspx?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511)

You're likely missing more features, all of upgrades are described in the linked documenation.